# Apply logical operation in R language for a vector

Tags: r, statistics

I need to find median of my vector which are under 22000 and above 35000
My code along with output is:

```
>x=c(23430,34650,43756,34835,24784,23795,27456,43599,23858,34835,43844,23979,32535,43662,34673,23564,23734,86325,34650,47845)
> y=x[x<22000 & x>35000]
> md=median(y)
> md
[1] NA
```

but I get NA when I try to compute the median.

Comment: No single value can be under 22000 AND above 35000. Either you want OR (`|`), or you've got your inequalities backwards.

Comment: Did you look at `y`? It's empty, `numeric(0)`. When you see something like this `md` that does not make sense to you, *trace the code back* to find where things go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You get `NA` since you have empty subset of `x`, i.e.,

```
> x[x<22000 & x>35000]
numeric(0)
```

but you can try the code below if it fits your objective

```
> median(x[x>=22000 & x<=35000])
[1] 26120
```

or

```
> median(x[x<22000 | x>35000])
[1] 43800
```